# How to create table partition with existing data?

Tags: oracle

I'm developer for banking project.Transaction table have 12 million records but it had not partition.So,Can i create partition this table with existing data?

Comment: Do you have a development environment? What have you tried?

Comment: No you can not partitioned a table with data. But you can create a new partitioned table and you can move 12 million records from non partitioned table to partition table. If you need more i will post some code

Comment: Development environment are -   Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production and Oracle BI Publisher 10g..Now, I development finance yearly report with BI but report query is not output data take long time 48 min.My paratmer date rate is 01/04/2015 to 31/07/2015 and 250 branch.

Comment: Dear Tarun,can i get your partition some code script.Please help me. Thank!

Comment: Before you go ahead with this, are you sure that partitioning the table solves an actual problem for you, and will not introduce new problems? This is a very big step to take.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot directly partition an existing non-partitioned table. You will need to create an interim table/new table depending on the following methods to partition:

- **[DBMS_REDEFINITION](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/partitioning-an-existing-table)**

  1. Create a Partitioned Interim Table
  2. Start the Redefinition Process
  3. Create Constraints and Indexes (Dependencies)
  4. Complete the Redefinition Process
- **[EXCHANGE PARTITION](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/partitioning-an-existing-table-using-exchange-partition#split_partition)**

  1. Create a Partitioned Destination Table
  2. EXCHANGE PARTITION
  3. SPLIT PARTITION (If required to split single large partition into smaller partitions)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following steps:

```
1. Create an empty table with partitioned structure as you want.
2. Populate the table with insert as select from previous table.
3. Optionally disable constraints before load.
```

If you want more efficient approach:

```
1. Create an empty table with partitioned structure as you want.
2. Create side table with data for specific partition (you can do it easily using create as select).
3. Exchange partition with the table created.
```

The process will be more efficient and can be automated with PL/SQL, but requires more work to do. The first approach is much easier but can take more time.